# Implicitly constructed variables in c++

Tags: c++

I'm getting to grips with c++ and there's one language feature I'm having particular trouble getting my head around.

I'm used to declaring and initialising a variable explicitly, but in c++ we sometimes seem to declare *and implicitly construct* a variable.

For example in this snippet rdev seems to be implicitly constructed (as it is subsequently used to construct a default_random_engine);

```
random_device rdev;
default_random_engine gen(rdev());
```

Can someone explain what's going on here? How can I tell this apart from a simple declaration such as `int myInt;` ?

Comment: All great answers, thanks. I've accepted @Puppy's answer as s/he explained why int is slightly different using nice easy words ;), but the technical detail in the other answers is also very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone explain what's going on here? How can I tell this apart
>   from a simple declaration such as int myInt;

They are both simple definitions.

The only difference is the properties of the type. `random_device` needs to be constructed, so it is. `int` does but people cried too much, so it isn't. Frankly, `int`'s behaviour is more of a language defect than something you actually want.

Ultimately, this is a property of the *types* and not the *definitions*.

Answer (score 5):

> Can someone explain what's going on here?

These are *definitions*, not just declarations. A variable definition creates the variable. In the first case, there's no initialiser, indicating that it should be default-initialised.

> How can I tell this apart from a simple declaration such as `int myInt;` ?

That's also a definition, creating the `int` variable and leaving it uninitialised.

You can declare a global variable without defining it:

```
extern int myInt;
```

`extern` indicates that it has external linkage, and is defined somewhere else. Other kinds of variable can't be declared without defining them.

Comment: Are these counted as definitions ? You don't actually define anything, you just declare the variable and it is given some memory.

Comment: @JID: Yes, these are definitions, defining the variables. It's the definition that causes the storage to be allocated and the variable initialised.

Answer (score 5):

```
random_device rdev; // creates an instance of random_device on the stack
                    // with default constructor (taking no arguments)

default_random_engine gen(  // creates an instance of default_random_engine
                            // on the stack
    rdev()                  // passing it the result of
                            // invocation of operator '()'
                            // on the instance rdev of random_device
);
```

Same in a more verbose form (with some C++11):

```
auto rdev = random_device {};
auto gen = default_random_engine { rdev.operator()() };
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated in C++ standard (8.5.11): `If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized; if no initialization is performed, an
object with automatic or dynamic storage duration has indeterminate value. [ Note: Objects with static or
thread storage duration are zero-initialized, see 3.6.2. — end note ]`

This is exactly your case: a variable definition without explicit initializer.
So, let's see what `default-initialized` means (8.5.7):

```
To default-initialize an object of type T means:
  — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9),
    the default constructor for T is called
    (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
 — if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
 — otherwise, no initialization is performed.
```

This clearly states the difference between your two examples:

- `random_device` is a class type, so its default constructor (the one without arguments) is implicitly called.
- `int` is neither a class type nor an array type, so no initialization is performed, and it will have an indeterminate value until you explicitly initialize it (by assigning a value to it).